# just: command alias could not be run because just could not find the shell

Tags: python, powershell, github-actions, powershell-core, just

I'd like to reference some commands I've set up in my `justfile` to be used in some steps of the CI pipeline (namely in my `actions.yaml` file) and I'm encountering issues. For personal preference, I'd like `just` commands to be run on `powershell` both locally and in the CI pipeline.

My `justfile` is as follows (it is meant to be run on a Windows machine):

```
# Use PowerShell instead of sh, https://just.systems/man/en/chapter_3.html
set shell := ["powershell.exe", "-c"]

help:
  @just --list

install:
  @echo " Installing dependencies"
  @poetry install --with dev

install-pre-commit:
  @echo " Setting up the hooks"
  @poetry run pre-commit install

check-project:
  @echo " Checking consistency between poetry.lock and pyproject.toml"
  @poetry check --lock
  @echo " Running the hooks against all files"
  @poetry run pre-commit run --all-files

ruff:
  @echo " Linting the project with Ruff"
  @poetry run ruff check src tests

ruff-show-violations:
  @echo " Linting the project with Ruff and show violations"
  @poetry run ruff check --show-source --show-fixes src tests

ruff-fix:
  @echo " Linting the project with Ruff and autofix violations (where possible)"
  @poetry run ruff check --fix src tests

black:
  @echo " Formatting the code with Black"
  @poetry run black src tests

black-check:
  @echo " Checking formatting advices from Black"
  @poetry run black --check --diff src tests

lint-and-format: ruff black

test:
  @echo " Testing code with pytest"
  @poetry run pytest --verbose tests

test-and-report-cov:
  @echo " Testing code with pytest and generating coverage report"
  @poetry run pytest --cov=./ --cov-report=xml
```

And here is part of my `actions.yaml` file:

```yaml
jobs:
  lint-and-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: pwsh

  steps:
    - name: Check out repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Setup python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

    - name: Install Poetry
      uses: snok/install-poetry@v1
      with:
        virtualenvs-create: true
        virtualenvs-in-project: true
        installer-parallel: true

    - name: Load cached venv if cache exists
      id: cached-poetry-dependencies
      uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        path: .venv
        key: venv-${{ runner.os }}-${{ steps.setup-python.outputs.python-version }}-${{ hashFiles('**/poetry.lock') }}

    - name: Install dependencies if cache does not exist
      if: steps.cached-poetry-dependencies.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
      run: poetry install --no-interaction --no-root

    - name: Install project
      run: poetry install --no-interaction

    - name: Setup just
      uses: taiki-e/install-action@just

    - name: Enforce code style (Ruff)
      run: just ruff-show-violations

    - name: Verify code formatting (Black)
      run: just black-check

    - name: Run tests
      run: just test

    - name: Generate test coverage report
      run: just test-and-report-cov

    - name: Upload coverage reports to Codecov
      uses: codecov/codecov-action@v3
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
        verbose: true
```

the most relevant steps in this regard being the definition of the default `shell`, *just*'s setup (`taiki-e/install-action@just`, as per [the manual](https://just.systems/man/en/chapter_6.html)) and the successive steps where `just` is invoked to run commands.

Along with the described setup, I get

```
> just ruff-show-violations
> shell: /usr/bin/pwsh -command ". '{0}'"
> env:
  > PYTHON_VERSION: 3.10
  > POETRY_VERSION: 1.6.1
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/pkgconfig
    Python_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64
    Python2_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64
    Python3_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib
    VENV: .venv/bin/activate
**error: Recipe `ruff-show-violations` could not be run because just could not find the shell: No such file or directory (os error 2)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.**
```

Based on the error message and in the idea of ensuring compatibility between `set shell := ["powershell.exe", "-c"]` in `justfile` and the setup of the default shell in `actions.yaml` (namely, trying to ensure alignment between the local execution environment and the Linux environment the Github Actions workflow runs on), I've tried to play around with these two with no luck. Neither setting `pwsh` nor `powershell` as default shell seems to work; specifying the shell at the level of single steps (with `shell:` option) doesn't work as well.

How to invoke `just` in GitHub Actions jobs' steps and run them on `powershell`?

### Update

Setting things up to run on `bash`, you won't incur in any issue. Namely, removing `set shell := ["powershell.exe", "-c"]` from `justfile` (thus reverting to `bash` by default) and specifying `bash` to be the default shell on which to run jobs in `actions.yaml` I could get a working configuration. However, I am yet to find a configuration that could properly run everything on `powershell`.

Not completely sure about that, but I also noticed that - no matter what the *default shell* configuration was - `taiki-e/install-action@just` kept on running on `bash`, which might be the root cause of the problem. Plus, it doesn't accept a `shell` input (that I tried to pass via `with: shell: ...` option) with which one could try to force the shell where to run the specific step on.
IOW, with

```yaml
jobs:
  lint-and-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: pwsh

  steps:
    ...
    ...
    - name: Setup just
      uses: taiki-e/install-action@just
      with:
        shell: pwsh
```

I got

```
Warning: Unexpected input(s) 'shell', valid inputs are ['tool', 'checksum']
Run taiki-e/install-action@just
  with:
    shell: pwsh
    tool: just
    checksum: true
  env:
    PYTHON_VERSION: 3.10
    POETRY_VERSION: 1.6.1
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/pkgconfig
    Python_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64
    Python2_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64
    Python3_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib
    VENV: .venv/bin/activate
Run bash --noprofile --norc "${GITHUB_ACTION_PATH:?}/main.sh"
info: host platform: x86_64_linux
info: installing just@latest
info: downloading https://github.com/casey/just/releases/download/1.23.0/just-1.23.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl.tar.gz
info: verifying sha256 checksum for just-1.23.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl.tar.gz
info: just installed at /home/runner/.cargo/bin/just
+ just --version
just 1.23.0
```

Comment: Did you try changing `powershell.exe` with `pwsh` or `powershell` in the `justfile`?

Comment: @Azeem I did. Unfortunately with no luck.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a repo. That'll be easier to iterate and fix. Regarding your update, an invalid input parameter will result in an error and that's what you're seeing as https://github.com/taiki-e/install-action does not support any `shell` [input parameter](https://github.com/taiki-e/install-action?tab=readme-ov-file#inputs).

Comment: Tried to reproduce your error with this [test workflow](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/7676873024/workflow) but it [works fine](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/7676873024) with `pwsh`. You need to verify this on your side as well. Maybe, there's something interfering with shell detection if you're in venv (not really sure what).

Comment: Thank you @Azeem! I'll try to see what's going wrong on my side.